# Older Internet Explorer and link in FancyBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox, fancybox-2

There is a simple example for using FancyBox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fbLink1').fancybox({
                'afterLoad': function() {
                    $('#fancyboxdiv').html('<h1>Fancybox first</h1>');
                    $('#fancyboxdiv').append('<a id="fbLink2" href="#fancyboxdiv" title="fancybox 2">Fancybox second</a>');
                },
                'afterClose': function() {
                    $('#fancyboxdiv').html('');
                }
            });
            $('#fbLink2').fancybox({
                'afterLoad': function() {
                    $('#fancyboxdiv').html('<h1>Fancybox second</h1>');
                    $('#fancyboxdiv').append('<a id="fbLink1" href="#fancyboxdiv" title="fancybox 1">Fancybox first</a>');
                },
                'afterClose': function() {
                    $('#fancyboxdiv').html('');
                }
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
<div id="fancyboxdiv" style="display: none;"></div>     
<a id="fbLink1" href="#fancyboxdiv" title="fancybox first">First</a><br />
<a id="fbLink2" href="#fancyboxdiv" title="fancybox first">Second</a><br />
```

In a Chrome-browser it works well, but in Internet Explorer it does not work. How can I make it work in IE8 and lower versions?

Comment: Probably use an older version of jQuery

Comment: What does not work? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I use jquery-1.9.0.min.js, and cannot see no errors in consol.

Answer (score 0):

First check the [fancybox documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support) -->FAQ tab --> No. 6.

This is the typical case where IE, in my opinion, is a better browser because it won't allow you to interact with elements that have a duplicated `ID` (IDs should be unique and two elements cannot have the same `ID` within the same document)

Having said that, what you are doing is adding a second element with an `ID` that has been previously defined :

```
$('#fancyboxdiv').append('<a id="fbLink2" href="#fancyboxdiv" title="fancybox 2">Fancybox second</a>');
```

and while other browsers will allow you to work with such duplicated ID, IE won't.

Since you already initialized fancybox for each element using their ID as selector
`$('#fbLink1').fancybox();` and `$('#fbLink2').fancybox();` then you just need to trigger each selector (using `onclick`) instead of adding a duplicated ID like :

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fbLink1').fancybox({
            beforeShow: function () {
                $('#fancyboxdiv').html('<h1>Fancybox first</h1>');
                $('#fancyboxdiv').append('<a onclick="javascript:$(\'#fbLink2\').click();" href="javascript:;" title="fancybox 2">Fancybox second</a>');
            },
            afterClose: function () {
                // $('#fancyboxdiv').html('');
                $('#fancyboxdiv').empty();
            }
        });
        $('#fbLink2').fancybox({
            beforeShow: function () {
                $('#fancyboxdiv').html('<h1>Fancybox second</h1>');
                $('#fancyboxdiv').append('<a onclick="javascript:$(\'#fbLink1\').click();" href="javascript:;" title="fancybox 1">Fancybox first</a>');
            },
            afterClose: function () {
                // $('#fancyboxdiv').html('');
                $('#fancyboxdiv').empty();
            }
        });
    }); // ready
})(jQuery);
```

That should work with any browser (tested with IE7)

Comment: I've less than 15 reputations.

Comment: @user2157361 : you don't need reputation to accept an answer.